# What causes style sheet bleed down into child widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtstylesheets

I have a child widget (QFrame) that has it's own style sheet setting. On this QFrame there are 4 labels that I do not want borders around. The parent widget to this QFrame is a QWidget and the border property is bleeding onto my QFrame labels.

I can make these go away with direct setting of the border for each label but I'd rather not have to do this. I just want to avoid the bleeddown. How do I do this?

BTW, both of these widgets (the parent and child) are created by a 3rd widget which is a QDialog. This QDialog created the parent, then the child, and passes the parent to the child in it's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried more specific selectors?  like selecting by object name, too?  `QLabel` inherits `QFrame`.  So when you tell your parent `QFrame` to behave a certain way, you are also telling all the `QObject`s that inherit `QFrame`, such as `QLabel` to also have the same style.

In the docs it mentions early on using `setObjectName` and `#objectName`.

> If we want the property to apply only to one specific QLineEdit, we
> can give it a name using `QObject::setObjectName()` and use an ID
> Selector to refer to it:

```
myDialog->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit#nameEdit { background-color: yellow }");
```

[Qt Documentation: Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

Later it has more examples of selectors:

[Complex Selector Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#complex-selector-example)

And like you already mentioned in your answer, an alternative would be to have a different style written out for your `QLabel`s.

The selectors in Qt StyleSheets behave with surprising similarity to what they do in CSS.  Ordering, additional selectors, etc, can get you to be very specific about which item(s) you are wanting a style to apply to.

Comment: I did try the specificity labels. I set an object name on the parent and then did the QWidget#objectName. Doing that stops the bleed down but now the parent is getting no style sheet applied. This is boggling my mind. I can do the same exact thing with other widgets to prove to myself that it works. It just don't work for this one single widget. There must be something in there that I can't see.

Comment: OK so I've been messing with style sheet specificity and have changed my question. Here's my code:

    const QString STYLE_SHEET = "background-color: rgba(x,x,x,y);"

Comment: Sorry about that last comment. Changed thought mid comment. I narrowed the problem to a single style sheet setting so I asked a new question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570389/losing-style-when-adding-specificity-to-a-qt-stylesheet