# Losing style when adding specificity to a Qt stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, stylesheet

Here's my code:

```
const QString STYLE_SHEET = "background-color: rgba(x,x,x,y);"
                            "border: 1px solid gray;"
                            "border-radius: 0px;"
                            "border-top: 1px solid red;"
                            "border-bottom: 1px solid blue;"
                            "border-radius: 0px;";
```

The SS is applied later in the code like this:

```
QWidget * myWidget;
myWidget = new QWidget(parent);
myWidget.setObjectName("myWidgetName");
myWidget.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET);
```

It works like a champ except that the borders bleed into a child QFrame. If I add specificity to STYLE_SHEET by bracketing it with the following:

```
const QString QWidget#myWidgetName { }
```

The STYLE_SHEET ceases to apply. It solves the bleed down to the child QFrame but my QWidget loses its style. And what good is a QWidget without style?

Answer (score 0):

```
const QString STYLE_SHEET = "QWidget#myWidgetName {\n"
                            "    background-color: rgba(x,x,x,y);\n"
                            "    border: 1px solid gray;\n"
                            "    border-radius: 0px;\n"
                            "    border-top: 1px solid red;\n"
                            "    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;\n"
                            "    border-radius: 0px;\n"
                            "}\n";
```

Comment: Tthanks for the answer but can you explain how the \n solve the problem? Don't get me wrong, I'm gonna try it. It's just that I'd like to know exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: I tried using the \n with no success. Any other ideas?

Comment: "\n" is just decoration. The `QWidget#myWidgetName` is most important. I've wrote this since your wrote something like this `const QString QWidget#objectName`. I assumed that this is exactly what you have in style sheet and this is wrong (also name from style sheet doesn't match to object name form code)!

Comment: OK well that was my mistake here. I typed objectName incorreclty. I fixed it.

I am back to my original problem. The style sheet does not apply.