# How can I apply a stylesheet to only a container frame and not the widgets within it in Qt designer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtstylesheets, qframe

I am currently designing a GUI in Qt Designer, and in a certain part of it, I want 4 QPushButtons in a QGridLayout within a frame widget. I want to apply a black border to this QFrame called `menu_frame`.

However, if I apply it, every button within it also gets a black border, breaking my design idea completely.

How can I only apply a black border to the frame widget itself, not to anything within it?

The stylesheet I use is:

```css
border: 1px solid black;
```

**Note:** I did not create any widget in my code, every widget was dragged to my GUI in Qt Designer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes style sheet bleed down into child widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551573/what-causes-style-sheet-bleed-down-into-child-widget)

Comment: Then please accept the duplicate proposal (there are other related posts I can add to that, but I don't have enough reputation to single-handle closure with the current tags).

Comment: @musicamante What are the related links?